Как выделить некоторые даты в CalendarDatePicker на Avalonia?
Мне необходимо в календаре CalendarDatePicker на Avalonia выделить некоторые даты.
Вот что я делаю сейчас, но цвет Background у выбранных дат меняется только при наведении на эту дату. Что я делаю не так?
<CalendarDatePicker Name="CalendarDate" SelectedDate="{Binding SelectedDate}" Width="200" >
    <CalendarDatePicker.Styles >
        <Style Selector="CalendarDayButton">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SelectedDatesMultiConverter}">
                    <Binding x:DataType="CalendarDayButton"/>
                    <Binding Path="$parent[CalendarDatePicker].DataContext.SelectedDates"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </CalendarDatePicker.Styles>
</CalendarDatePicker>

